# An elaboration of a step in the proof of that the outer measure of an interval is its length from Royden .

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation

The part of the proof is given below:

> [image]

but I do not understand why (in the second line) $m^{*}([a,b]) \leq l((a-\epsilon, b + \epsilon))$, what is the justification of this step?

Comment: What is the definition of $m^*([a,b])$?  Is it the greatest lower bound of the lengths of all open intervals containing $[a,b]$?

Comment: $\{(a-\epsilon, b + \epsilon)\}$ is a countable covering of $[a,b]$ by open intervals, and the outer measure of $[a,b]$ is the infimum of the sums of lengths of all such coverings.

Comment: Yes, I got it @JesseMadnick thanks